# How to fix "com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.RepositoryException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out"

Tags: apache, tfs, bamboo

I am using Bamboo for builds and TFS as a repo and I am quite new with these systems.

The issue is that I get error messages saying:
"Bamboo Unable to detect changes"

and here is the chunk from the log file:
    com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.RepositoryException:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out at

```
com.stellarity.bamboo.repository.TfsRepository.collectChanges(TfsRepository.java:404)
at com.stellarity.bamboo.repository.TfsRepository.collectChangesSinceLastBuild(TfsRepository.java:289)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.trigger.DefaultChangeDetectionManager.collectChangesWithRetry(DefaultChangeDetectionManager.java:556)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.trigger.DefaultChangeDetectionManager.lambda$createBuildRepositoryChanges$159(DefaultChangeDetectionManager.java:427)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.variable.CustomVariableContextImpl.withVariableSubstitutor(CustomVariableContextImpl.java:221)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.trigger.DefaultChangeDetectionManager.collectChangesSinceLastBuildInternal(DefaultChangeDetectionManager.java:362)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.trigger.DefaultChangeDetectionManager.collectChangesSinceRevisions(DefaultChangeDetectionManager.java:310)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.trigger.DefaultChangeDetectionManager.collectChangesSinceRevisions(DefaultChangeDetectionManager.java:195)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.trigger.DefaultChangeDetectionManager.collectChangesSinceLastBuildIfTriggered(DefaultChangeDetectionManager.java:133)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.trigger.ChangeDetectionListenerAction.testIfBuildShouldStart(ChangeDetectionListenerAction.java:114)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.PlanExecutionManagerImpl$3.call(PlanExecutionManagerImpl.java:510)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.PlanExecutionManagerImpl$3.call(PlanExecutionManagerImpl.java:493)
at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.ManagedLocks$ManagedLockImpl.withLock(ManagedLocks.java:293)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.PlanExecutionLockServiceImpl.lock(PlanExecutionLockServiceImpl.java:85)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.PlanExecutionManagerImpl.doWithProcessLock(PlanExecutionManagerImpl.java:784)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.PlanExecutionManagerImpl.startConditionalBuild(PlanExecutionManagerImpl.java:492)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.PlanExecutionManagerImpl.start(PlanExecutionManagerImpl.java:566)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.PlanExecutionManagerImpl.start(PlanExecutionManagerImpl.java:583)
at     com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.DelegatingPlanExecutionManager.start(DelegatingPlanExecutionManager.java:95)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.NonBlockingPlanExecutionServiceImpl$4.startPlanExecution(NonBlockingPlanExecutionServiceImpl.java:234)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.NonBlockingPlanExecutionServiceImpl$4.lambda$call$253(NonBlockingPlanExecutionServiceImpl.java:220)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.util.CacheAwareness$3.call(CacheAwareness.java:159)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.util.CacheAwareness$3.call(CacheAwareness.java:155)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.util.CacheAwareness.withValuesOlderThanTimestampReloaded(CacheAwareness.java:188)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.util.CacheAwareness.withValuesOlderThanTimestampReloaded(CacheAwareness.java:154)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.util.CacheAwareness.withValuesOlderThanTimestampReloaded(CacheAwareness.java:219)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.NonBlockingPlanExecutionServiceImpl$4.call(NonBlockingPlanExecutionServiceImpl.java:219)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.NonBlockingPlanExecutionServiceImpl$4.call(NonBlockingPlanExecutionServiceImpl.java:202)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.utils.BambooRunnables$1.run(BambooRunnables.java:51)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper.runWith(ImpersonationHelper.java:31)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper.runWithSystemAuthority(ImpersonationHelper.java:20)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper$1.run(ImpersonationHelper.java:52)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at com.stellarity.bamboo.repository.TfsRepository.validateUrl(TfsRepository.java:627)
at com.stellarity.bamboo.repository.TfsRepository.getTeamProjectCollection(TfsRepository.java:633)
at com.stellarity.bamboo.repository.TfsRepository.collectChanges(TfsRepository.java:322)
```

I searched a lot but I couldn't find any possible reason or solution.

Please help!!!!!!

Comment: @jobair ahmed any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean this issue only occurs when using TFS as a source repository? What's the result if you are using another one such as github repository  .Then the issue is not related to TFS.

Comment: We only use TFS, so I can't test it against another repo @Patrick-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

Check Firewall. Is Bamboo server able to connect to TFS ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do telnet to TFS server from Bamboo on the port which TFS is listening . If the traffic is going , then ports are open else port is closed

`telnet <IP of tfs> port`

Comment: it is connected. this is not a constant error. it is happening from time to time